# How to trim part of object after subtraction?

Tags: sketch-app

I'm using Sketch 3 to make a horizontal subtraction composed by four ovals out of a rectangle. See images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Problem is though that the rectangle is still in "one piece". I can't simply delete the upper part half of it, something I'm used to do previously with Illustrator. Here instead I get some sort of masking between the objects. But I don't want my ovals to mask the rectangle, I want the ovals to use as a cookie cutter to cut out what I want to keep from the rectangle.

How do I go about to make a complete trimming of the rectangle using the ovals so that everything is discarded except the lower wave form object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `Layer > Paths > Flatten`.

Then you can double click either one of them, to select the individual shape.

---

or with the icon in the toolbar.

[image]

<sup>Can't remember if that sits there by default, but you can right-click the toolbar and go `Customize toolbar`</sup>

Comment: Well thank you! That was the exact desired effect I was looking for!